# CSS Elements Scale in Aspect Ratio & Position In the Browser Window

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
<body class="home page-template-default page page-id-7 logged-in homepage" onload="UI.initialise()">
   <div class="wrapper">

      <main role="main">
        <section>               
            <div id="container" class="container">
                <video autoplay="true" id="intervieweefeed">
                </video>
                <canvas id="intervieweecanvas"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div id="container2" class="container2">
                <video autoplay="true" id="echoborgfeed">
                </video>
                <canvas id="echoborgcanvas"></canvas>
            </div>

         </section>
      </main>
   </div>
</body>
```

I am then using the following CSS:

```
.wrapper{max-width:1920px; margin:0 auto;}
.container {
width: 44.6vw;
height: 57.5vh;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
display: block;
margin-left: 4.4%;
margin-top: 1.3%;
position: relative;
}

.container2 {
width: 44.6vw;
height: 57.5vh;
float: right;
overflow: hidden;
display: block;
margin-right: 4.4%;
margin-top: 1.3%;
position: relative;
}

#intervieweefeed, #echoborgfeed {
width: 100%;
position: relative;
}

canvas{position:absolute; left:0; top:0;}
```

This works in a full screen browser window on a 16:9 aspect ratio. However, if the browser window breaks from this aspect ratio, then I either have an issue with the height and or the width depending on how the screen is being made smaller.

What I'd like to do is scale the whole page down so that the content always displays at 16:9 and scales down the containers with the videos as the screen gets smaller. In addition, I'd also want to make sure that the margins the containers use also scale down as well.

Could someone advise me on how I would achieve this?

Comment: width: 100%;
height: 100%; try this it may work

Comment: I presume you mean on the wrapper div or the body?

Comment: in class="wrapper", make a change in wrapper class.